# How to choose the same input more than once [selectize.js]?

Tags: shiny, selectize.js

I'm building a shiny app and would appreciate a little help with selectize.js. I've been all around the internet and can't seem to find a way to keep the initial list of choices untouched after choosing one.

I have a `selectizeInput` panel with `multiple = TRUE` I want to be able to choose the same element twice and have an array of ["First", "First"]. There seem to be no option about it. Everytime I choose an element it can't be chosen again.

Any ideas?

Comment: `test <- c(input$selectizeInputname[1],input$selectizeInputname[1])`

Comment: I want the user to be able to select an already selected choice again. I know how to create an array of same objects. Maybe the question was misleading a bit

Comment: The behavior of selectizeInput is that the selected item disappear from the menu, so if I understand this correctly, the question is in desire to stop that from happening?

Comment: Contrl+select will work for him by default

Comment: @user4065758 you can clear the selection using selectize.clear(). But more of can you put your code also here or jsfiddle link for more accurate information.

Comment: Hi, did you try using option groups? https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/pull/1128